How to ask to install package with command-not-found instead of suggesting to install it
command-not-found asks a question like this when the command is not found in Kali Linux:
Command 'co' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install rcs
Do you want to install it? (N/y)

In Debian, however, it only suggests to install the package with
Command 'co' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install rcs

How do I make Debian ask to install the package with command-not-found?

Add COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_INSTALL_PROMPT=1 to /etc/environment and reboot with reboot. This will enable prompting to install the package for the command. It works for all shell environments supporting command-not-found.
